# Creating a NSDateFormatter reusable class

Tags: ios, json, nsdateformatter

In my app a JSON date string gets parsed different times (in my view controller, detailed view controller and in a share this page action). I want to set up only one NSDateFormatter and reuse it whenever I have to.

So far I have a NSObject file (UpcomingRelease)

UpcomingRelease.h

```
+ (NSString *) formattedDate:(NSString *)jsonDateString;
```

**UpcomingRelease.m**

```
+ (NSString *) formattedDate:(NSString *)jsonDateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *readableDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:jsonDateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:readableDate];
}
```

Now in my detailedViewController I imported "UpcomingRelease.h" and I have this code inside my viewLoad

```
NSString *formattedDate = [self formattedDate:[_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]];
self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedDate];
```

But I get an error saying: "No visible @interface for 'ReleaseViewController' declares the selector 'formattedDate:'". If I add the formattedDate code directly to the page it works (using - instead of +) but not when I try to call it from the NSObject.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Put the code in the .m file, not the .h file - you have it backwards (or it's a typo in your question).

Comment: is `release_date` meant to be `formattedDate:`?

Comment: You're not reusing one dateFormatter, you're recreating it. But more importantly, you're not using it at all. You created a variable with the same name that's shadowing your function, which you're not calling correctly, or incorrectly. Simply not calling it at all. First comment should be addressed before.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, sorry. @rmaddy.

Comment: "release_date" is the date string thats being formatted. @wattson12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
NSString *formattedDate = [self formattedDate:[_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]];
```

to:

```
NSString *formattedDate = [UpcomingRelease formattedDate:[_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]];
```

Since you defined `formattedDate:` to be a class method, you need to call it on the class.

And as was pointed out in the comments, your code if very inefficient because you recreate the date formatter instance every time you use the method.

```
+ (NSString *) formattedDate:(NSString *)jsonDateString {
    static NSDateFormatter *jsonFormatter = nil;
    static NSDateFormatter *readableFormatter = nil;
    if (!jsonFormatter) {
        jsonFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [jsonFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
        readableFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [readableFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
        // Note - this code will not deal with a user changing the Region Format on their device
    }

    NSDate *readableDate = [jsonFormatter dateFromString:jsonDateString];

    return [readableFormatter stringFromDate:readableDate];
}
```

Comment: Your answer works, thanks. How can I make my code more efficient?

Comment: See my updated answer for one solution for more efficient code.

Comment: `dispatch_once()` could be used alternatively.

Comment: @MartinR Correct. I almost used that but was lazy and used the simple `if` since I could do that from memory? :)